# Synthetic division to find zeroes using imaginary numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I am given a polynomial with a zero of -i. I understand that by definition "i" must also be a zero. The problem asks me to use synthetic division to find all zeroes. My textbook only gives two examples using non-complex numbers, and after an exhaustive Google search I cannot find any calculators that show how to find a zero using only -i or i, only for complex numbers such as "2-i", etc. Can anyone please help me with the steps I should take to find any other zeroes, or if the answer is only "-i" and "i"?

Edit: Using Oscar Lanzi's suggestion, I was able to use a calculator to work out the synthetic division. I had the correct answer, but I was burning out a little since I have been doing math since late Friday night.

To give more info on the polynomial, it is $P(x)=x^3+3x^2+x+3$ and $-i$ is given as a zero. So to address the answer below, the polynomial has real coefficients.
I hope this answers some questions.

Comment: Can't you just use the calculator that does complex numbers and put $0$ for the real part of the (proposed) root?

Comment: I guess I could if I wasn't trying to make this harder than it actually is. :) Thank you, Oscar, for framing this more simply. I suppose I am stressing myself more than necessary over it.

Comment: You are welcome @Colby, even here people sonetines forget that $0$ can be used as a number.

Comment: @Colby Can you give us more detail about the polynomial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am given a polynomial with a zero of -i. I understand that by definition "i" must also be a zero.

That's true *only* if the given polynomial has *real* coefficients, and in that case it follows by the [Complex conjugate root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem) (not by definition).

The following will asume that the question is indeed about a polynomial with real coefficients, but you should spell that out in the post.

> The problem asks me to use synthetic division to find all zeroes.

Since $i$ and $-i$ are both roots, the original polynomial is divisible by $(x+i)(x-i) = x^2 +1$. Using [Synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division#Expanded_synthetic_division) by monic polynomials (sometimes called *expanded* synthetic division) you can divide the original polynomial by $x^2 + 1$. The quotient will be of degree 2 less than the original, and presumably easier to solve by other methods in order to find the rest of the roots.

---

[ EDIT ]    Taking for example the polynomial $x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 3 = 0$ added to the original question, this one *has* real coefficients, so knowing that $-i$ is a root *does* imply that $i$ is a root as well. Dividing by $x^2+1$ using synthetic division gives:

$$
\begin{align}
x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 3 & = (x^3 + x) - x + (3 x^2 + 3) - 3 + x + 3 \\
 & = x(x^2+1) + 3(x^2+1) = \\
 & = (x+3)(x^2+1)
\end{align}
$$

The quotient of the division is the first degree polynomial $x+3$ with the unique root $x=-3$.

---

[ EDIT #2 ]    While the above answers the question as posed (using synthetic division) it may be worth pointing out that in the simple case of a 3rd degree polynomial with 2 known roots the easiest way to find the remaining root is using any of Vieta's formulas, rather than division and factorization. In the given example $x_1 = i$, $x_2 = -i$ and $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = -3$ therefore $x_3 = -3$.

Comment: Thank you dxiv, I understand that now. I was going off of what was in my textbook, which I had read so many times in the past 2 days any new information I might have gathered was simply ignored by my brain. I appreciate the input and the suggestions about using other methods to find the rest of the roots. However it is a homework question and I am required to show work using synthetic division.

Comment: @Colby The above *is* about using synthetic division to solve it, as you asked in the title. The "*other methods*" only referred to how to solve the polynomial you determined to be the quotient following the synthetic division. I'll add the example you edited in to make that point clear.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Of course since $i$ and $-i$ are both zeros, and $(x-i)(x+i) = (x^2 +1)$, then we would use synthetic division to divide by -1 which would find the real root. Something i did not do. However, I feel i have actually learned it now. If only learning from your mistakes positively influenced your GPA.

Comment: @Colby GPA is important and unescapable, but having learnt something is what matters in the end. This is not meant as an inspirational platitude, it will make more sense as time goes by.